# Synchronizing Outlook 2010 Calendar with Sharepoint 2010 website Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sharepoint

How do I synchronize my Outlook 2010 calendar to SharePoint 2010 website?

I am able to synchronize SharePoint Calendar into my Outlook calendar but not able to do Outlook Calendar (meetings, Data) into SharePoint Calendar.

When my office people go into our intranet site, I just want them to see my calendar in SharePoint which updates the data from Outlook and displays it but this calendar data on SharePoint should only be read-only to other users.

Answer (score 1):

We have been dealing with SharePoint/Outlook issues for a while. The only native option is to manually drag and drop the appointment from your personal calendar to the SharePoint calendar (assuming you can view the calendar in SharePoint).

Comment: I tried it and worked. But this can be done when there are only few. But, its difficult to do it all the time. And most important thing is, meetings in outlook can be added anytime. So, its really very difficult for a person viewing my sharepoint calender to view my meeting in Outlook, if the copy process is not done. So, I need some permanent solution for this. Anyway, thanks a lot for your prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on a third party Outlook add-in for this called ProperSync. The next release will have automated calender syncing.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a shared calendar in exchange/outlook.
Next in Sharepoint add that exchange/outlook calendar as an overlay to you Sharepoint site calendar:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/use-a-group-calendar-HA101810606.aspx

This is a rather clean solution.

Answer (score -1):

You must create an email address for the shared calendar in SharePoint in order to send your meetings, appointments to sync with SharePoint.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this precisely within a SharePoint 2010 website?