# How to Synchronize Outlook Personal Calendar with SharePoint 2013 Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to display outlook calendar in SharePoint 2013 calendar. When user add event/meeting in outlook calendar it should also be added in SharePoint 2013 calendar.

Comment: Can't you simply share the calendar with the Sharepoint calendar?  Otherwise this appears to require third-party software to acomplish http://superuser.com/questions/295518/synchronizing-outlook-2010-calendar-with-sharepoint-2010-website-calendar?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

[Synchronise Sharepoint with outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-small-business-help/synchronize-sharepoint-content-with-outlook-HA102774420.aspx)